# tkinter , python , buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I want to add a button like

```
b = Button(app_name,text="..." , command = any_function)
```

is it possible to use function with a parameter like

```
b = Button(app_name, text="..." , command = any_function(7))
```

I had tried

```
 (...)
 def cash(price):
        global total
        total.set(total.get() + price)

total = IntVar()
total.set(0)

b1 = Button(app,text = "one ",width = 10,command = cash(1))
b1.pack()
b2 = Button(app,text = "two ",width = 10,command = cash(10))
b2.pack()
b3 = Button(app,text = "three ",width = 10,command = cash(100))
b3.pack()
b4 = Button(app,text = "four ",width = 10,command = cash(1000))
b4.pack()

l_total = Label(app,textvariable = total)
l_total.pack()
(...)
```

But `l_total` already as 1111 when the program run ( 1000+100+10+1) like I had pressed the four buttons and also the buttons doesnt add values to `l_total` . I just want to know why it doesnt work as I know a solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written:

```
b = Button(app_name, text="..." , command = any_function(7))
```

… isn't *passing a function* as the `command`, it's *calling* a function, then *passing its result* as the `command`.

---

What you need to do is to define a new function that, when called with no arguments, calls `any_function(7)`. Like this:

```
def any_function_7():
    return any_function(7)
b = Button(app_name, text="..." , command = any_function_7)
```

Or, using the shorter [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) syntax for defining functions:

```
b = Button(app_name, text="..." , command = lambda: any_function(7))
```

Wrapping an expression up in a function like this, then passing the function around, is a way of deferring the function until later. It can be hard to get your head around, but once you do, it's incredibly useful all over the place.

---

Another way to look at it is *partially applying* the function, which gives you a thing that you can *finish* applying later on. There's a [`partial`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function in the standard library that does this for you:

```
from functools import partial
b = Button(app_name, text="..." , command = partial(any_function, 7))
```

But you can also do it yourself:

```
def make_any_function_partial(i):
    def wrapped():
        return any_function(i)
    return wrapped
b = Button(app_name, text="..." , command = make_any_function_partial(7))
```

And then you can see how this is really just the same trick as using `def` or `lambda`, plus another trick on top of it: it's a function that returns a function. So, while you may be calling `make_any_function_partial` and passing its result to `command`, just as in your original attempt, the difference is that the result is itself a function.