# Tkinter button to change png image in frame

Tags: python, button, tkinter

i've tried looking around but could only find people trying to change the image ON a button, not WITH a button

this is what i have thus far

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
from random import randrange
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import tkMessageBox
import tkFont
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Randomizer")
root.minsize(900,600)
root.maxsize(900,600)
adress = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\ClassPics\Class.png"
playerclass1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(adress))
panel = tk.Label(root, image = playerclass1)
panel.pack(side='top')

def randomizer():
    playerclassV = randrange(0,10)
    if playerclassV == 0:
        adress = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\ClassPics\1.png"
    elif playerclassV == 1:    
        adress = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\ClassPics\2.png"
    elif playerclassV == 2:  
        adress = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\ClassPics\3.png"
    elif playerclassV == 3:  
        adress = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\ClassPics\4.png"
    elif playerclassV == 4:  
        adress = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\ClassPics\5.png"
    elif playerclassV == 5:  
        adress = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\ClassPics\6.png"
    elif playerclassV == 6:  
        adress = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\ClassPics\7.png"
    elif playerclassV == 7:  
        adress = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\ClassPics\8.png"
    else:  
        adress = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\ClassPics\9.png"
    playerclass = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(adress))
    panel.configure(image = playerclass)
    panel.image = playerclass
Randomize = Button ( root, text="Randomize", justify="center", width=20, command=randomizer())
Randomize.pack(side = 'bottom')
root.mainloop()
```

the idea is to start of in a window with just the initial image and the randomize button, and the randomize button replacing the initial image with 1 of 9 images chosen randomly with the randrange function. right now it's not displaying the initial image, but rather going straight to the function (displaying one of the 9 latter pics, not the initial), and the button does nothing

please help

Comment: `command=randomizer` without the `()`

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are **calling** the function.
You should use `command=randomizer` . Don't use `()` if you wish to not call the function the moment you run the program.
If you wish to send some arguments(visibly not in this case), you can use `command=lambda:randomizer(args)`.
Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895821/tkinter-python-buttons/21895923#21895923) for more detailed answer